# Brute-force a Code Lock

Tags: java, algorithm, object

I'm working on a method which solves code locks utilizing a brute-force algorithm, but I'm running out of ideas as to how I can do this efficiently. [This image shows how my program is structured.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c5T3.png)

The idea is that the algorithm should work on any amount of rows, whom each can contain any amount of columns (with in reason, lets say no more than 50 total squares). It should start by trying to place '2' into the first square, then '3' in the next empty square, and so on. If the method returns true, it stops. If not it restarts by trying to place '3' into the first square, then '3' in the next,...

The lock is considered open when every square in every row have the correct digit. The method then returns true. It will only return false when every possible sequence is tried, and none worked (meaning something went wrong elsewhere in the program).

Let's only consider the first row only, and say that the correct sequence is "3 - 4 - 9". Following the image above, this should return true:

```
//Returns true for a = 0, b = 0, c = 1 --- x = 0, y = 1, z = 2

allEmptySquares[a][b].putValue(allEmptySquares[a][b].getPossibleSolutions.someArray[c]);
allEmptySquares[x][y].putValue(allEmptySquares[x][y].getPossibleSolutions.someArray[z]);
```

I have tried using for-loops, and making the method recursive, but I can't get it to work when the solution has z > c.

Any tips as to how I should go about writing this?

Edit: I'm more interested in your ideas for possible solutions rather than you writing the code for me.

Edit: I forgot to mention a big detail. For every square that gets a new digit, there will be fewer alternatives for the other squares. Think of it like Sudoku. This means that when someArray.length = 0, the method restarts as explained in the second paragraph. The last square will have someArray.length = 1, if all the other squares have received the correct digits.

Edit: The possible solutions, and which squares are pre-filled, are decided elsewhere in the program, therefore this method needs to be as 'generic' as possible.

Comment: You understand this problem is too large to actually solve, right? There are 10^50 solutions in your "within reason" example.  You should write code to solve a simpler problem, like 3 digit locks, then show us the code.

Comment: But you have an algorithm - you called it brute force. What you seem to be asking for is : "how do I implement this algorithm?" - which is code. As markspace points out, 10^50 is quite large - for example, if you checked one code every nanosecond, it would take 3.16887646 × 10^33 years...

Comment: On the other hand, you've put some excellent detail into your question, but it's still a bit mysterious. Why start with 2 and not 1? Why does get possible solutions return only [3, 7, 9] and not [1 ...9]?

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt a setup I used for Sudoku, once... it's still brute force, but slightly more sophisticated about constraints.

The basic flow is Choose - Constrain - Mark - Backtrack. Start by assigning a value to the first "open" square, (just go with the first possible value.) Then, run constraint checking to limit all the values of other squares. If any of them are limited down to only a single value, assign that, and then re-run constraint addition. If you find yourself with everything in a valid assignment, return that; if you find yourself with multiple choices, pick one and try again; if you find yourself with no valid choices for any square, go back to the last choice you made and try the next one.

(The easiest way to set up the "Go back" setup is with recursive function calls, so the call stack is the same as the search stack.)